# Getting form from click event in Controller in ExtJS?

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs-mvc

I am extending the example given in http://docs.sencha.com/architect/2-0/#!/guide/views_forms_extjs to use a more MVC centric approach. So in service of that I want to move the on click handler from the view to a newly create controller.

I have the click even working fine, but I have no idea how to operate on the form from the context of the controller (the view was using this.getForm()).

Here is what I have so far,

```
Ext.define('LoginExample.controller.LoginController', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',


    onLoginButtonClick: function(button, e, options) {
        console.log('button clicked');


        if (this.getForm().isValid()) {
            this.getForm().submit({
                url: 'login.php',
                success: function(form, action) {
                    Ext.Msg.alert('Login Successful!');
                },
                failure: function(form, action) {
                    Ext.Msg.alert('Login Failed!');
                }
            });
        }
    },


    init: function() {
        this.control({
            "#loginButton": {
                click: this.onLoginButtonClick
            }
        });
    }

});
```

Obviously the this in the context of onLoginButtonClick is no longer the view and is instead the controller.

Given the parameters given to me, (Ext.button.Button button, Event e, Object options), how do I get the submit on the appropriate form?

I should note this using ExtJS 4.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
button.up('form');
```

will do the trick.

To get the BasicForm object to operate on, use

> button.up('form').getForm()

Comment: That make sense to me that should work, but when I do that I get "Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'isValid'".

Comment: that's because form has no isValid() method. A form does have an inner BasicForm though, which has an isValid() method. You have to use the odd form.form.isValid() expression to get it :)

http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.form.Basic-method-isValid

Comment: Thanks, that works. You can also use .getForm() instead of form. Or do a query using Ext.ComponentQuery.query("#formid")[0].getForm()